# Set length on when required Yii2 rules

Tags: validation, yii2, rules

```
 [['shortcode'],'string', 'length' => [8, 11]],// first
 ['shortcode','required', // second
                'when' => function($model) {
                  // code here
                },
 ],
```

How can I combined my rules `length` only on if I set it to `required` ? Thanks in advance.

For now, Im always ending up checking for min length.

Answer (score 1):

Best option (and it should always be used) is to use [scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios). I don't know any other solution to this, only with scenarios. In case you haven't used it yet, here's how you implement:

```
public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        'scenario_global' => [<attributes list you want to validate>],
        'scenario_shortcode_only' => ['shortcode']
    ];
}


public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['shortcode'], 'string', 'length' => [8, 11], 'on' => 'scenario_shortcode_only'],
        [['shortcode'], 'required', 'on' => 'scenario_shortcode_only'],

        // If you need shortcode with different rule set, then use 'except' instead of 'on'
    ];
}
```

When you declare scenario `scenario_shortcode_only`, only those rules with `'on' => 'scenario_shortcode_only'` will be validated while others will be ignored.